# probe processor voltage in linux

Tags: cpu, redhat-enterprise-linux, voltage, lm-sensors

I am in a redhat server

I've tried to use lm-sensors to detect my processor's voltage,

just like CPU-Z in windows environment.

But after I using the command "sensor-detect",

only processor's temperature printed out,

how can I make processor's voltage be printed out?

Do I need to load some modules?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: plus: is the voltage showed in the message after using command "sudo dmidecode -t processor" the processor's voltage currently?
I get 1.3V but it seems that it always show 1.3V

Comment: plus again:
I found I use sensors-detect and super I/O chips showed:
found unknown chip with ID 0x0001

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The way that I found to read the CPU voltage was using cpu-x, an open source program.

This program may need a few libraries to work. In my case I needed to install libcpuid which i didn't find in the main repository, so I installed from the source.

To install libcpuid:

```
git clone https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid.git
cd libcpuid
libtoolize
autoreconf --install
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

To install cpu-x:

```
git clone https://github.com/X0rg/CPU-X.git
cd CPU-X
mkdir build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Then I could run:

```
sudo cpu-x
```

And the output shows the voltage:

```
    Fornecedor: Intel
        Codinome: Sandy Bridge (Core i7)
          Pacote: 
      Tecnologia: 32 nm
        *Voltagem: 0,770 V*
 Especificação: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
        Família: 0X6
   Ext. Família: 0X6
          Modelo: 0XA
     Ext. Modelo: 0X2A
           Temp.: 66°C
        Stepping: 7
    Instruções: HT, MMX, SSE(1, 2, 3, 3S, 4.1, 4.2), AVX(1), AES, CLMUL, VT-x, x86-64
             ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/X0rg/CPU-X.git
cd CPU-X
mkdir build
# you forgot this command
cd build  
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```